# Taskhost Process has high CPU when using VirtualBox

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am running a Ubuntu VirtualBox-VM on my Windows 10 host machine.

After the VM is running for some time (not at the beginning), the process **taskhostw.exe** uses much of the CPU. I normaly use ssh to connect to the VM, but using a GUI is also possible. I am using a shared folder.

When I shutdown the VM, **taskhostw.exe** goes back to normal. I was using Process Explorer to investigate the problem, it only showed stuff related to Microsoft or my Antivirus Solution.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The process command is **taskhostw.exe Time**

Comment: Make sure your guest is not using more than one half of your CPUs or Memory

Comment: @John Please explain why this could help when the process taking too much CPU is part of the host system.

Comment: I use Virtual Machines a lot.  I keep guests to 1 CPU and 3 to 4 GB of memory.   Guests never drag down my host even if the guest is struggling

Comment: Use Process Monitor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see which kind of activity take place.

Comment: In Process Monitor, the process with the pid which has the high CPU usage does not generate any output. There is another one running which does create output.

Comment: Having the same issue. Currently the only **workaround**: pause VM till taskhostw.exe finishes its processing (it takes a couple of seconds). So seems that taskhostw.exe somehow is blocked by VM?